# Why does my code ignore the Exception?

Tags: java, arrays, object, if-statement, illegalargumentexception

My code should make entering anything other than a letter or a '$' in discountCode String result in throwing an exception however this doesn't happen. The user can type anything and still not receive an exception message.
Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

```
private String normalizeDiscountCode(String discountCode) {
  String upperDiscountCode = discountCode.toUpperCase();

    for (char i : upperDiscountCode.toCharArray()) {
      if (Character.isLetter(i) || i == '$') {
        return upperDiscountCode;
      } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid discount code");
        }
    }
    return upperDiscountCode;
  }

  public void applyDiscountCode(String discountCode) {
    this.discountCode = normalizeDiscountCode(discountCode);
  }
}
```

Comment: You're `return`ing on the first iteration.

Comment: try passing `"123"` as an argument

Comment: Thanks, how should I proceed for it to continue down instead?

Comment: Also consider using a different exception than IllegalArgumentException: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208544/when-should-an-illegalargumentexception-be-thrown

Comment: Your code will fail only if the first character does not meet the conditions. Replace `return upperDiscountCode;` with `continue` to make your code work as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if(!Character.isLetter(i) && i != '$') {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid discount code");
}
return upperDiscountCode;
```

..although I'm still a little confused about what you are trying to accomplish on line 6 by returning the upperDiscountCode, which should just  return if the first character is a letter or '$', therefore not checking any other letters.

Comment: That's exactly the point. The return statement is the bug and should be removed.

Comment: I don't think `&&` ,it should be `||` or not ?

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 version:

```
private String normalizeDiscountCode(String discountCode) {
    String upperDiscountCode = discountCode.toUpperCase();
    if (upperDiscountCode.chars()
            .allMatch(c -> Character.isLetter(c) || c == '$')) {
        return upperDiscountCode;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid discount code");
}
```