# how to pass latitude and longitude in retrofit for nearest road API

Tags: android, api, retrofit

this is the request format

```
https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/nearestRoads?parameters&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

here i need to pass latitude and longitude as parameter points, something like this

```
https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/nearestRoads?points=60.170880,24.942795|60.170879,24.942796|60.170877,24.942796&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

i tried to pass it like

```
  @POST("nearestRoads?points&key=my_api_key")
Call<SnappedPoints> getNearestRoad(@FieldMap Double map);
```

by calling

```
Call<SnappedPoints> call = retrofitClientMap.getNearestRoad(stringStringMap.put(latLng3.latitude,latLng3.longitude));
```

but it shows an illegal exception , can any one help have an idea to solve it

Comment: isn't `@Query` used for `@GET` method ?

Comment: my mistake I thought it was @GET method.

Comment: are you missing `@FormUrlEncoded` in your code or only in question.

Comment: @POST("nearestRoads?points=9.994932,76.288885&key=my_key")
    Call<SnappedPoints> getNearestRoad();   this should be the format but have to pass that values 9.994932,76.288885 inside function getNearestRoad()

Comment: An illegal exception? Do you mean an illegal argument [exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15209875/1008011)? If so, it's probably because you are passing in the wrong argument to getNearestRoad(...). You are declaring @FieldMap with a `Double` (object) but when calling, you are passing in a `double` (primitive): stringStringMap.put(60.170880,24.942795)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it by calling api service like

```
 @POST("nearestRoads?key=my_api_key")
    // Call<MySnappedPoints> getNearestRoad();
Call<MySnappedPoints> getNearestRoad(@Query("points") String points);
```

calling it by

```
 String test = Double.toString(mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target.latitude) + "," + Double.toString(mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target.longitude);
    Call<MySnappedPoints> call = retrofitClientMap.getNearestRoad(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Have you tried something like this**

```
@POST("nearestRoads?key=my_api_key")
Call<SnappedPoints> getNearestRoad(@Field("points") String points);
```

then pass your points as `String` to this method